# converting formatted json object to array of objects by keys and sum up on each level

Tags: javascript, node.js

Have the following tree json object:

```
{
  "Season1": {
    "Title1": {
      "a1": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      },
      "a2": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      }
    },
    "Title2": {
      "c1": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      },
      "d2": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tried to format the json using the following function:

```
function Format(obj){
    return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, val]) => {
        let o = { name: key}
        if(Object.keys(val).some(function(k) {return typeof val[k] === 'object'})){
            o['_children'] = Format(val)
        } else {
            Object.keys(val).map(function(a){
                o[a] = val[a]
            })
        }
        return [o]
    })
}
```

That will return an array of nested objects by keys:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Season1",
    "_children": [
      {
        "name": "Title1",
        "_children": [
          {
            "name": "a1",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          },
          {
            "name": "a2",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Title2",
        "_children": [
          {
            "name": "c1",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          },
          {
            "name": "d2",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The challenge is to calculate the subtotal of the bottom level keys, which are val1, val2, val3, in each parent levels **recursively**, .e.g. "Title1", "Title2", and "Season1", therefore after populating the output into a table can fill up the blank subtotal cells. The expected output should look like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Season1",
    "_children": [
      {
        "name": "Title1",
        "_children": [
          {
            "name": "a1",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300",
          },
          {
            "name": "a2",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300",
          }
        ],
        "val1": 200,
        "val2": 400,
        "val3": 600
      },
      {
        "name": "Title2",
        "_children": [
          {
            "name": "c1",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300",
          },
          {
            "name": "d2",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300",
          }
        ],
        "val1": 400,
        "val2": 400,
        "val3": 600
      }
    ],
    "val1": 600,
    "val2": 800,
    "val3": 1200
  }
]
```

How to update the Format function for that purpose? Can someone share any thoughts or solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also edit your recursive function like below. I'm accumulating the sum at each level of recursion and passing it up to the call stack

```js
data = {
  Season1: {
    Title1: {
      a1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      },
      a2: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    },
    Title2: {
      c1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      },
      d2: {
        val1: "300",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    }
  }
};


function merge(srcObj, destObj){
  Object.keys(srcObj).forEach(key => {
    if(destObj[key]) {
      destObj[key] = destObj[key] + srcObj[key]
    }
    else{
      destObj[key] = srcObj[key];
    }
  });
  return destObj;
}



function Format(obj, valObj = {}, level = 0) { 
    valObj[level] = {};
    return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, val]) => {
      let o = { name: key };
      if (typeof val === "object") {
        o["_children"] = Format(val, valObj, level + 1);
        valObj[level] = merge(valObj[level+1],valObj[level] || {});
        if(level <2){
          o = { ...o, ...valObj[level + 1]};
        }       
      } else {     
        valObj[level][key] =  Number.parseInt(val);
        o["value"] = val;
      }
      return [o];
    });
}

a =  Format(data);




console.log(a);
```

For your modified format function, you can try like below.

```js
data = {
  Season1: {
    Title1: {
      a1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      },
      a2: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    },
    Title2: {
      c1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      },
      d2: {
        val1: "300",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    }
  }
};

function merge(srcObj, destObj){
  Object.keys(srcObj).forEach(key => {
    if(destObj[key]) {
      destObj[key] = destObj[key] + srcObj[key]
    }
    else{
      destObj[key] = srcObj[key];
    }
  });
  return destObj;
}


function Format(obj, valObj = {}, level=0){
    valObj[level] = {};
    return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, val]) => {
        let o = { name: key}
        if(Object.keys(val).some(function(k) {return typeof val[k] === 'object'})){
            o['_children'] = Format(val, valObj, level + 1);
          valObj[level] = merge(valObj[level+1],valObj[level] || {});
            if(level <2){
              o = { ...o, ...valObj[level + 1]};
            }
        } else {
            Object.keys(val).map(function(a){
                valObj[level][a] = (valObj[level][a] || 0) + Number.parseInt(val[a]);
                o[a] = val[a]
            })
        }
        return [o];
    })
}


a =  Format(data);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: thanks @nithin, the solution was effective. Later I update the function Format() in the question to make the bottom level neater, which removes the _children object at the bottom and directly put the keys value pairs with the names. 
I tried to modify your solution but couldn't get it work after the Format function changed, can you help advise how?

Comment: @ctlkkc No problem. I have tweaked the code to work with the new Format function. Please check the updated answer. Please mark right answer / upvote if this was helpful :). Good day :)

Comment: Thanks. @nithin can you also help in a similar question? thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741717/converting-formatted-json-object-to-array-of-objects-on-the-same-level-flatten

Answer (score 0):

You could update all levels, except the most nested one.

```js
function sum(array, sums = {}) {
    var update;
    array.forEach(o => {
        if (!o._children) {
            sums[o.name] = (sums[o.name] || 0) + +o.value;
            return;
        }
        var x = {}
        sum(o._children, x) && Object.assign(o, x);
        Object.keys(x).forEach(k => sums[k] = (sums[k] || 0) + x[k]);
        update = true;
    });
    return update;
}

var data = [{ name: "Season1", _children: [{ name: "Title1", _children: [{ name: "a1", _children: [{ name: "val1", value: "100" }, { name: "val2", value: "200" }, { name: "val3", value: "300" }] }, { name: "a2", _children: [{ name: "val1", value: "150" }, { name: "val2", value: "260" }, { name: "val3", value: "370" }] }] }, { name: "Title2", _children: [{ name: "c1", _children: [{ name: "val1", value: "110" }, { name: "val2", value: "220" }, { name: "val3", value: "330" }] }, { name: "d2", _children: [{ name: "val1", value: "101" }, { name: "val2", value: "202" }, { name: "val3", value: "303" }] }] }] }];

sum(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```