# converting formatted json object to array of objects on the same level (flatten) and sum up on each level

Tags: javascript, node.js

Have the following tree json object:

```
{
  "Season1": {
    "Title1": {
      "a1": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      },
      "a2": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      }
    },
    "Title2": {
      "c1": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      },
      "d2": {
        "val1": "100",
        "val2": "200",
        "val3": "300"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tried to format the json using the following function:

```
function Format(obj){
    return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, val]) => {
        let o = { name: key}
        if(Object.keys(val).some(function(k) {return typeof val[k] === 'object'})){
            o['_children'] = Format(val)
        } else {
            Object.keys(val).map(function(a){
                o[a] = val[a]
            })
        }
        return [o]
    })
}
```

That will return an array of nested objects by keys:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Season1",
    "_children": [
      {
        "name": "Title1",
        "_children": [
          {
            "name": "a1",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          },
          {
            "name": "a2",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Title2",
        "_children": [
          {
            "name": "c1",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          },
          {
            "name": "d2",
            "val1": "100",
            "val2": "200",
            "val3": "300"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The challenge is to calculate putting them on to the same level as well as adding subtotal of the bottom level keys, which are val1, val2, val3, in each parent levels recursively, .e.g. "Title1", "Title2", and "Season1", therefore after populating the output into a table can fill up the blank subtotal cells. And the children level should be indented with **4 white space** depending on how deep the level is. The expected output should look like:

```
[
  {"name": "Season1", "val1": 600, "val2": 800, "val3": 1200},
  {"name": "    Title1", "val1": 200, "val2": 400, "val3": 600},
  {"name": "        a1", "val1": "100", "val2": "200", "val3": "300"},
  {"name": "        a2", "val1": "100", "val2": "200","val3": "300"},
  {"name": "    Title2","val1": 400, "val2": 400, "val3": 600},
  {"name": "        c1", "val1": "100", "val2": "200", "val3": "300"},
  {"name": "        d2", "val1": "100", "val2": "200", "val3": "300"},
]
```

How to update the Format function for that purpose? Can someone share any thoughts or solution? Thanks!

Comment: If you are planning to these data with d3js, you can do this translation easily using d3js, without writing vanilajs.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works! Might be a little tricky to explain the code.

I have added a couple of comments at relevant parts of code.

```js
var data = {
  Season1: {
    Title1: {
      a1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "150",
        val3: "100"
      },
      a2: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    },
    Title2: {
      c1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      },
      d2: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    }
  },
  Season2: {
    Title1: {
      a1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      },
      a2: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    },
    Title2: {
      c1: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      },
      d2: {
        val1: "100",
        val2: "200",
        val3: "300"
      }
    }
  }
};

function Format(obj, depth = 0) {
  return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, val]) => {
    if (
      Object.keys(val).some(function(k) {
        return typeof val[k] === "object";
      })
    ) {
      // Pad keys with spaces based on depth
      let o = {
        name: key.padStart(depth * 4 + key.length)
      };
      const children = Format(val, depth + 1);
      // Get the sum of children that are only only one level deep 
      const childrenSum = children
        .filter(
          ({
            name
          }) =>
          name.length - name.replace(/\s/g, "").length === (depth + 1) * 4
        )
        // Filter out the name key as they are not numbers 
        .reduce((acc, temp) => {
          Object.entries(temp)
            .filter(([key, val]) => key !== "name")
            .forEach(([key, val]) => {
              acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + Number(val);
            });
          return acc;
        }, {});
      o = { ...o,
        ...childrenSum
      };
      return [o, ...children];
    } else {
      let o = {
        name: key.padStart(depth * 4 + key.length)
      };
      Object.keys(val).map(function(a) {
        o[a] = val[a];
      });
      return [o];
    }
  });
}

console.log(Format(data));
```